# Space telescope spectroscopic data for stellar classification using Wien's law

Tags: observational-astronomy, amateur-observing, spectroscopy, stellar-classification

My goal is to make a simple project which consists of classifying stars by applying [Wien's displacement law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law).

I need public spectroscopic data about different stars from a space telescope, so that I can find the stars' peak wavelengths. Also, I need the spectoscopic data to include wavelengths from 50 nm to about 860 nm.

Here's my request: I'd like a recommendation for a space telescope that would be adequate for these purposes.

Comment: Probably no single satellite covers your full range, but see https://archive.stsci.edu/missions-and-data

Comment: How much do you need down to 50nm in the UV ? Hubble (HST)-STIS cuts off at 115nm, HST-COS at 82nm and Swift-UVOT around 150nm. As @JamesK says this is likely to need combining data, for which the HST [CALSPEC](https://www.stsci.edu/hst/instrumentation/reference-data-for-calibration-and-tools/astronomical-catalogs/calspec) set of calibration standards is likely your best if you don't that farthest bit of the far UV

Comment: Does it have to be a space telescope? There are plenty of ground-based telescopes that have tons of data for this such as SDSS.

Comment: @zephyr you can't do shorter wavelengths than ~300nm from the ground due to the ozone cutoff in atmospheric transmission

Comment: Note that spectroscopic classification doesn't use Wien's law but it is an instructive exercise nonetheless.